# Trying to understand why mathematical operations between Python Decimal datatype and float datatype are unsupported

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I encountered the following errors recently as I was using the Decimal object type in my python code to [mitigate rounding off error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#mitigating-round-off-error-with-increased-precision) as suggested in the Pydocs.

```
In [173]: Decimal(10) * 0.5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-173-c778d6cdfd9f> in <module>()
----> 1 Decimal(10) * 0.5

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

This problems occurs for all floats that are used to compute with Decimal objects for all other kinds of operations. However the problem is non-existent for operations with integers:

```
In [175]: Decimal(10)*5
Out[175]: Decimal('50')
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: For exactly that reason - *"to mitigate rounding off error"*, which doesn't exist when you're using an integer (as they can be represented exactly). You need e.g. `Decimal(10) * Decimal.from_float(0.5)` or `Decimal(10) * Decimal('0.5')`.

Comment: but I'm wondering if there is any fundamental reason? Like they want to prevent some kind of overflow or something that is why the exception was thrown? Was the exception thrown as a result of some kind of checking done beforehand, or as a result of the operation be carried out but that resulted in some error at the OS level that ended up with the exception?

Comment: The fundamental reason is that most people are using `Decimal` precisely to avoid issues with float accuracy; if you allow them to then multiply by a regular (inaccurate) float, what's the point? The `Decimal` class is designed to raise a `TypeError` when you try to operate on it with a float to prevent you from doing something foolish.